# Adding coolant into reservoir it comes out overflow on radiator

Tags: coolant, gmc, sierra, radiator-overflow

I changed water pump 02 gmc sierra 1500 and of course I had to drain the coolant system to do that . As I am adding coolant back into the system through the reservoir it is coming out radiator overflow ? If I put cap on reservoir it stops . Unscrew it , starts again ? Can’t figure out what’s going on . Suggestions or how to fix it would be so helpful . Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Which engine is in your Sierra? (4.3L V6, or 4.8/5.3/6.0L V8)

Comment: I have the 4.3L v6 in my truck

Comment: You said the coolant is coming out of the radiator overflow ... I'm not aware that the radiator on these trucks have an overflow *on the radiator*. Can you explain where exactly the coolant is coming from? Is it coming out of the tube which stems from where the cap is at on the reservoir?

Comment: Yes it’s coming out the radiator by the peacock I believe it’s called . Where I drained it at they have hose the other side I thought was overflow .

Comment: I went and bought new Petcock and that worked there isn’t overflow but that’s what I thought it was . It’s good as of now ran it for 35 min or so and it’s not leaking at all . We will see tomorrow how it drives

Comment: Thank you Paulster you helped great deal bc I thought that was overflow for some reason . I appreciate your time on that , thank youb